# How can I remove instance "driver" from test's classes

Tags: java, oop, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

Can anybody help me with my question:

**How can I remove instance `driver` from `BaseTest` class but use it here and in children classes?**

I using POM for building testing-framework through with Selenium + TestNG + Maven.
For example I have next `BaseTest` class:

```
package com.google.test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class BaseTest {

    protected WebDriver driver;

    protected WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {
        if (driver == null) {
            initializeDriver();
            setPropertyWindow();
            setPropertyTimeOut();
        }
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
        delay(3000);
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.close();
        }
    }

    public void initializeDriver() {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilitiesFirefox = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilitiesFirefox.setCapability("marionette", true);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "e:\\Autotests\\TestGoogle\\src\\test\\resources\\Geckodriver 0.16.1\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilitiesFirefox);
    }

    public void setPropertyWindow() {
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    public void setPropertyTimeOut() {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void delay (long millisec) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millisec);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This question has appeared becouse I have one more instance driver in class `BasePage`:

```
package com.google.pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class BasePage {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.google.com/ncr";
    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected static final int TIME_OUT = 10;

    protected WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public WebElement assertThat(ExpectedCondition<WebElement> condition) {
        return (new WebDriverWait(driver, TIME_OUT)).until(condition);
    }
}
```

I want to remove instance `driver` from `BaseTest` class but leave it in class `BasePage`. So that I leave only one instance of `driver` in Project. And my tests will know only about test's logic but will not know about specific realization (for example in the current time it is selenium, but in future it will be possible selenide or other tool).
Maybe I have to create new class Webdriver and inside create static instance `driver` and method getter() which I can use? Or another way? I don't figure out what way is better in this case and more right with point OOP principles.

**The full project you can find here** - [TestGoogle on GitHub](https://github.com/Andrei1982/TestGoogle)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do is have a `DriverManager` static object that has the driver setup and teardown (all static). It also has a static driver instance and a static getter for it.

Both test and page objects can just call DriverManager.getDriver(). In your system, the test object would also call the DriverManager setup/teardown from its own setup/teardown. All the concerns about driver specifics go into DriverManager. Any driver-related utilities such as custom waits go there, too.

Some people frown upon static objects. But you can just as well make DriverManager a singleton:

```
static private final instance = new DriverManager();

static public DriverManager getInstance() {
    return instance;
}
```

Static fields are initialized when the class is first referenced.

Comment: Which realization of Singleton do you suggest use here? For example, for using launching multi tests at the same time?

Comment: I don't do multiple tests in parallel from one project - I tend to get issues when the browser window is fully covered, though in theory this should work. So I can just do a usual singleton with `static private DriverManager instance`. For multiple tests at the same time, I would probably have an instance of DriverManager stored in the test object. and then create the page object from the test object - so the test object's instance would be the master.

Comment: Do not really understand. Do you have example of this realization?

Comment: I have updated the answer with a simple singleton implementation.

Comment: Sorry, but in this case will possible exceptions... Pattern Singleton maybe seem very simple but always exist nuances which we have to solve.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove WebDriver instance from `BaseTest`.
2. Make `BaseTest` extend `BasePage`.

Like this:

```
public class BaseTest extends BasePage {
    protected WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: No, no, no. How do you imagine it - `Tests` Inherited from `Pages`? Where is logic? This essence of Page Object Pattern - split the logic. This variant is very easy for physical realization of problem (simple syntax and no more) but I try to solve logical realization this problem.